# Script to disable select if option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you write a script to disable a select if you have two selects (both with ids) and an option in the first select is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have tagged the question with jQuery, I'll give you an idea of how to do it using jQuery:

```
$("#firstSelectId").change(function() {
    var first = $(this);
    $("#secondSelectId").prop("disabled", function() {
        return first.val() === "whatever";
    });
});
```

Note that the above assumes you want to enable the second select again if a different option was selected. Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/kJr3y/).

Comment: Brilliant! How do you modify this so that more than one options can be selected to disable the second select?

Comment: And is there a way I can use ids instead of values to identify the options?

Comment: You should be able to use what I've given you as a base to get started. What you're now asking for are relatively simple changes that you should be able to figure out with a bit of reading/experimenting. Try some things out, and ask specific questions on StackOverflow if you get stuck. That'll be far more effective than me writing all your code for you.

Comment: I've solved the first problem but am stumped by the second... Would really appreciate it and will accept your answer. Sorry, I know it's bad of me I've just spent hours fiddling with something for which a solution escapes me.

Comment: If you mean you want to use `id` values from the `option` elements, you probably want to look into the `:selected` pseudo-selector (check the jQuery API) to find the selected option. You can do this in the anonymous function passed to `prop`. Something along the lines of `return first.children(":selected").attr("id") === "someId";`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$('#first').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != '') { // '' is default value??
    $('#second').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $('#second').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use something like:

```
if($("#selectbox1 option:selected").val() == ...)
```

to see what was selected.

and then use

```
$("#selectbox2").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

to disable that other box.